# Roleplaying system with minimal focus on combat

Tags: investigation, non-combat, exploration, intrigue

I'm looking to play a tabletop RPG with a couple of friends, and I own the main D&D 4e books. However, we'd like to play a game which is focused more on intrigue and adventure rather than combat. A good deal of the D&D adventures I've seen online are very much based on one combat encounter after the next.

Are there any good systems (or ways to adapt D&D 4e) which focus on storytelling/roleplaying/adventure and less on stats and dice rolls, with few or no combat encounters, or whose combat encounters don't require grids, skill sheets, etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Diabolik, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Unfortunately we ruled recommendation requests off topic a couple of years ago. However, when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat] and can ask about this with us informally there.

Comment: I'll say that there *definitely* are RPGs with more focus on intrigue and investigation. Though we've found SE is a poor tool for getting recommendations, I'm sure you'll have no trouble getting many interesting recommendations along those lines in a more traditional forum-style site, and I wish you happy exploring of the options!